# How to go to the previously viewed page in various PDF viewers, e.g TexWorks'?

Tags: pdf, viewers

Suppose my PDF document is produced by `pdflatex` and while viewing the document I follow a link and go from *A* to *B* within the document. How do I go back from *B* to *A*? In other words where is the browser-back button of the viewer?

Adobe Reader has several choices: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or actual buttons. But the behavior is not standard. For example how does TeXWorks viewer do the same?

Comment: You can find shortcuts for SumatraPDF [on this page](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/manual.html).

Comment: I noticed TeXStudio has this feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only use Okular, which has shortcuts and toolbar buttons for "back" and "forward" navigation. The predefined shortcuts seem to be Alt+Shift+Left / Alt+Shift+Right, but you can always redefine them.

Answer (score 10):

Evince 3.38.1 has the following shortcuts:

- Alt+N: Next page visited
- Alt+P: Previous page visited

Comment: These shortcuts work on Document Viewer 41.3 as well

Comment: Nice. Anyone knows if these shortcuts can be mapped to Alt + Left / Alt + Right instead?

Comment: Not sure whether this is the default, but I had to press Alt, release the key, and press N or P after that.

Answer (score 5):

In `evince` (a Gnome PDF viewer apparently), I found that there was no `Back` button by default, but you just have to right-click on the toolbar area, and a toolbar settings menu comes up. You click on that and then drag a `Back` button to the toolbar area.

In operation, you click on this `Back` button in `evince`, and it gives a menu of all of the previous pages you have visited, in reverse order. So you can click on the top page number to go back one step, and so forth.

Comment: The back button of evince is not really working as I would expect: 1) Click reference A to jump to some chapter. 2) Scroll for several pages. 3) Click reference B to jump somewhere else. 4) Click the back button. I end up at the page where reference A is pointing to, not the one on which I clicked the link B.

Comment: Also works for Atril, thanks.

Comment: At present this feature seems not to be working properly; cf.: https://askubuntu.com/a/1045491/738083

Answer (score 1):

Xreader (v. 2.0.2) offers functionality to move back and forward in the viewing history. See also here (similar question): https://askubuntu.com/a/1160347/738083

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have a mouse with 5 buttons, you can use the 4 and 5 button to go forward/backward (at least in Evince).